# Why is declaring a variable in For loop necessary?

Tags: python, for-loop

Im Python beginner and i im really confused with for loop in Python and have trouble understanding it properly.  Before transitioning to Python i learned basics of programming using C.

And the way i understand for loop in python is that it iterates over a certain given sequence. And for each element in sequence it executes following block of code.

Therefore for example for this for loop in Python:

```
for i in range (0,10):
    if i==5:
        i+=3
    print i
```

Equivalent for loop in C would look like this if my understanding is correct:

```
int r[] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(r)/sizeof(r[0]); j++) {
    int i = r[j];
    if (i == 5)
        i += 3;
}
```

The way i understand this is that variable used in c (in this example variable j) for executing block of code certain number of times is not needed.Since now number of elements in sequence determines number of times loop gets executed. Or in other words number of elements represents a value that is used to determine how many times to execute loop.

But then why do we need a variable declared in for loop if we already have value which instructs how many times to execute block of code which is why loops are used in first place ? Why is it not possible to write in Python for example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
for a:
    print("Hello")
```

Shouldn't this loop simply use number of elements as parameter/value that instructs it how many times to execute following code?

Why is additional variable needed in case like this when it doesn't serve any purpose in terms of what we try to accomplish with loop.Which is to execute certain instructions certain number of times?

Im sure im missing something and someone can hopefully help clear up any confusions.

Comment: The idea of a missing variable, or unused variable is covered by a convention of using `_`. So in your last snippet you would need: `for _ in a:`

Comment: not sure how this translates to C languages but the for loop in python is used as a counter by can also act in an OOP way by iterating over any object, eg `for key, val in json_dict.items():` or `for val1, val2 in zip(list1,list2):`

Comment: If you fix the syntax error in your first Python code fragment *print(i)* and run that code, review the output. It may not be what you expected. That should lead you to learn about the built-in *range* generator

Comment: If you think about `for a:` - what would that mean? It would be totally unclear to me. Instead, it makes more sense to assign the sequence's values to a variable via the loop declaration. `for element in sequence:` is clear - iterate all elements of the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

Python actually has a built-in way of dealing with this, and `for a does not work as it looks like you missed a variable, which the interpreter does not like

Instead, try using `for _ in a:`, which is the modern convention.

## Code

````py
a = [1,2,3]
for _ in a:
    print("Hello") ```
````

Comment: `for _ in a:` still assigns to a variable; you can use `_` within the loop (try `print(_)` in the example). It "fixes" the code but I don't think this answers why a variable is necessary here.

Comment: In other languages(C++) there is a concept of goto there you can make a loop with if condition.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a short answer is: **"because Python assumes you may need a reference to the current item while iterating over an iterable"**

In the C example you are giving, `j` is an index so it serves to retrieve the item with `r[j]`, but Python lets you reference the item `r[j]` directly - and you access it via the variable that you declare.

Python's [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) says:

> The for statement in Python differs a bit from what you may be used to
> in C or Pascal. Rather than always iterating over an arithmetic
> progression of numbers (like in Pascal), or giving the user the
> ability to define both the iteration step and halting condition (as
> C), Python’s for statement iterates over the items of any sequence (a
> list or a string), in the order that they appear in the sequence.

That in itself may explain your confusion when relating to C. Perhaps you are thinking of things like [`forEach`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop) ?

In Python, you have to declare a variable that will reference the current item in the iterable you are iterating over, but that doesn't mean you have to use that reference (hence the examples with `_` which is just a convention for a reference that you have no intention to use)

Python lets you iterate over just about anything iterable, the following will work just fine:

```
a = ["no compelling", "reason to have", "an arithmetic progression of numbers"]
for _ in a:
    print("Hello")
```